# Numerical first derivative of a surface

Tags: r, algorithm

Are there any good algorithms to find the numerically the first derivative of a surface?

E.g., to find the first numerical derivative of a normal distribution, I started with:

```
# Generate some data
library(mvtnorm)
library(raster)

xy <- expand.grid(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.1), y = seq(-3, 3, 0.1))
xy$den <- dmvnorm(xy, mean = c(0, 0))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(xy)

# A naive approach
rx <- r
for (i in 2:(nrow(rx) - 1)) {
  for (j in 2:(ncol(rx) - 1)) {
    rx[i, j] <- abs(r[i, j - 1] - r[i, j + 1])
  }
}

ry <- r
for (i in 2:(nrow(rx) - 1)) {
  for (j in 2:(ncol(rx) - 1)) {
    ry[i, j] <- abs(r[i - 1, j] - r[i + 1, j])
  }
}

d1 <- rx + ry
```

But I am not sure if thats an acceptable way, and could not any background paper discussing this.

Comment: No absolute value, and you need to divide by the twice step size 2*dx resp. 2*dy.

Comment: When you can write your surfaces as images you probably could use image processing tools for this task. Then have a look at e.g. ``EBImage::filter2`` and at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_derivatives

Comment: Adding the partial derivatives does not necessarily make sense. Derivatives are always defined with respect to a certain direction. If you want a value that describes the surface locally, you might want to use the gradient or its length.